# onNewIntent called after finish() executed

Tags: android

I have an application consisting of a sticky service and a separate SINGLE_TOP activity. The service receives messages from a server then launches the Activity using startActivity(intent). When all messages have been dismissed by the user I terminate the Activity using finish(). I was under the impression and from my research so is everyone else that once finish() had executed any subsequent startActivity(intent) calls would come through the onCreate not the onNewIntent. However, if I send new messages at the exact time I dismiss the last message I (albeit rarely) see an onNewIntent after the finish() has executed but prior to the onDestroy.

Has anyone experienced this situation and is there a simple solution?

The solution I am contemplating would be to:
1. tell the service that the Activity is stopping prior to executing the finish()
2. Wait for an OK from the service.
3. the service would then queue any messages until it was informed the Activity had stopped
4. have the activities onDestroy inform the service it has stopped
5. service would send any queue'd messages.

It would all be much simpler if finish() gaurenteed an onCreate.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: According to my log there is a several hundred millisecond gap between the finish() executing and the onNewIntent.

Comment: I'm assuming from your comment that you believe the next intent should come through the onCreate after finish() has executed?

Comment: So when is your Activity removed from the top of the stack, when finish() has executed or after onDestroy has executed? If it's the latter then that's a poor design.

Comment: In both the cases `Activity` is removed from top of the stack. Maybe you should try a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain you about `singleTop`.

Consider Activities A,B and C. Let us assume that B is `singleTop` and other two are `standard`. So this is how that stack will look.

`A -> B -> C -> B -> new Instance of B will be created`

`A -> B -> C -> B -> B -> onNewIntent() called, new Instance of B is NOT created`

`finish()` in turn calls `onDestroy()` so in both the cases your activity is removed from top of the stack.

Maybe in your case this is happening :

`A -> B -> C -> finish() -> B -> onNewIntent() called`

`A -> B -> C -> B -> finish() -> finish() -> B -> onNewIntent() called`